# How to selectively filter videos from YouTube with Squid

Tags: youtube, squid

Here's the scenario:  I have a 7 and 4 year old and I'm setting up a computer for them to use which would include unsupervised times.  I've set up squid so that they can only get to websites that are in my whitelist for them, but I'd like to make the videos from Khan Academy available as well.  The problem is that the videos are all hosted on YouTube and I definitely don't want to allow unfettered access to that.  How can I do that?

**Update:** Ideally I would like to allow the embedded video on the KhanAcademy page.  That means that I probably don't have anything to filter on aside from the youtube link itself.  Maybe I could approach this a different way and filter out pages that contain the start of the YouTube title tag on the page:

```
"<title>\sYouTube - "
```

I'm thinking I may need to incorporate DansGuardian to accomplish that...

Comment: Did you find any success with any approach?

Comment: @Faust:  I did not.  I played around a little without success, but eventually gave up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will fit the bill for everything, but I have had good luck with [DansGuardian](http://dansguardian.org/)  It lets you set up scoring, sort of like Bayesian filtering used to block spam emails.  It might be difficult to filter youtube videos, since there is little text content to work with, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: I suppose the text would be  From: khanacademy or by khanacademy..so might be simple.  not sure how to do that though..

Comment: I doubt this will work because much of the text on the youtube page is actually loaded by AJAX calls after the page load and it would be difficult to filter on.

Comment: The other problem is that the video is embedded in the KhanAcademy page, so there really isn't any text to filter on.